# How o setup call backurl in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to setup callback url for blockchain.info receive api.

Below is a **php** example but i don't know to to setup this in laravel

```
$my_callback_url = 'https://mystore.com?invoice_id=058921123&secret='.$secret;
```

my route is following

```
Route::get('btc_ipn/{invoice_id}/{secret}',['as'=>'btc_ipn','uses'=>'HomeController@btcIPN']);
```

I tried but ipn doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build URL for the route you've shown, do something like this:

```
$url = route('btc_ipn', ['invoice_id' => $invoice->id, 'secret' => $secret]);
```

If you need to create a route for this URL:

```
https://mystore.com?invoice_id=058921123&secret=' . $secret;
```

Create a `get` or `post` route:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@btcIPN');
```

Then in the controller:

```
public function btcIPN()
{
    $invoiceId = request('invoice_id');
    $secret = request('secret');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To meet routes you created as

```
Route::get('btc_ipn/{invoice_id}/{secret}',['as'=>'btc_ipn','uses'=>'HomeController@btcIPN']);
```

Your url should be like

```
$invoice_id = $request->invoice_id;
$secret = $request->secret;
$my_callback_url = "/btc_ipn/$invoice_id/$secret";
```

If you want to return with some data like error use

```
return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['msg', 'The Message']);
```